# Default props are not available in first time render ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using react and redux and calling a async actions from my component lifecycle hook `componentDidMount`. **this.props.user** is updated by the the server call. I initialised with default value.

The problem is at line 1 , where 1st time the console log prints

1. **Object {name: "Test"}** and second time it prints
2. **Object {user: Array[30], name: "Test"}**

Why `this.props` doesn't have the default user array property at first time rending ?

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';
    import { fetchUsers } from "./fetchGithubUser"
    import { connect } from "react-redux"

    const styles = {
      fontFamily: 'sans-serif',
      textAlign: 'center',
      color:'green',
    };

    @connect((store) => {
      return {
        user: store.users,
      };
    })
    class App extends React.Component{

      componentDidMount() {
        this.props.dispatch(fetchUsers())
      }
      render(){

        console.log(this.props) // line 1

        return(
          <div style={styles}>
            <p> Hello World </p>
            <ChildComponent />
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    App.defaultProps = {
      user: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      name: 'Test'
    }
    export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if you wish to pass default props to the component that is connected through the store using connect decorator, you would define the default props as static members of the class

```
@connect((store) => {
  return {
    user: store.users,
  };
})
class App extends React.Component{
  static defaultProps = {
     user: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     name: 'Test'
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(fetchUsers())
  }
  render(){

    console.log(this.props) // line 1

    return(
      <div style={styles}>
        <p> Hello World </p>
        <ChildComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

The other way to handle this would be to define initial state with the reducer

```
const InitialState = {
   user: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
   name: 'Test'
}
const myReducer = (state = InitialState, action) => {}
```

Comment: approach 1 is working fine, but i am having trouble with approach 2. https://codesandbox.io/s/65nm6kx4r

Comment: that is because you had a typo, `const InitialState = {
  users: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],   //<-- should be users instead of user
  name: 'Test' 
}` .  https://codesandbox.io/s/3kv053wzpp

Answer (score 1):

In your `@connect` function, you pass in the `user` prop as coming from your store, which will overwrite default props. You can do

```
  return {
    user: store.users || [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  };
```

Or alternately you can pre-populate your redux store with fake user data.

Comment: how to pre-populate redux store with fake data ? I am creating store as `const store = createStore(myReducer, middleware);`

Comment: Most redux examples show how to do this: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/api/createStore.md#example. `function myReducer(state = {someDefaultState}, action) {`